# Isometry of spheres/hypersurfaces and more generally Riemannian manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be two spheres (of different radius) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-1$. Suppose there is a Riemannian isometry between them (so a diffeomorphism and isometry). Then distances must be preserved in some way... but does this not constrain the radiuses of the spheres?

Consider the two spheres as being hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

For example, consider two intervals. Then I don't think there can be a isometry between them unless the intervals are of the same size. Am I right?

Does requiring a diffeomorphism to be an isometry restrict the range of manifolds we work with massively?

Comment: Yes, an isometry preserves distances and volumes, so two spheres are isometric if and only if they have the same radius (since the radius determines the surface area, for example). For an example, you can then look at the spheres $S(r) = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid |x| = r\}$. All of these are diffeomorphic, but not isomorphic for different values of $r$. Manifolds up to isometry is a much, much larger class of objects than manifolds up to diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, but don't you mean "much smaller class"?

Comment: No, there are "more" manifolds up to isometry than up to diffeomorphism; see the spheres of different radii.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I was thinking "two manifolds which are isometric are definitely diffeomorphic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An isometry must preserve  intrinsic quantities  like scalar and sectional curvature, which are proportional to some negative power of the radius, so spheres of the same dimension which are isometric, even locally, must have the same radius. An exception is 1-spheres (circles); there are no local invariants, so they are all locally isometric, but not globally, because the total length (circumference), which is intrinsic,  is proportional to the radius.